# pass a Empty Object Array Model to another View controller Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

i have a Object Array to store Contact Data in a Model . also there is a view controller with two task . Modify and Create Contacts in this view Controller . in Modify Mode i pass model data in 
table view didSelectRow and there is now problem in there . **but in create Mode when add button touched in first VC app make this crash :  Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value** . **the Main question it is How i can Pass Empty Model To VC2 Witout Crash.**

Model :

```
class ContactModel : NSObject {
    var identifier : String!
    var thumbnailImageData : UIImage?
    var givenName : String!
    var familyName : String!
    var phoneNumbers : [String]!
    var emailAddresses : [String]!

    override init()
    {
        super.init();
    }

    init(identi:String,img:UIImage?,name:String,family:String,phone:[String],email:[String]) {
        self.identifier = identi
        self.thumbnailImageData = img
        self.givenName = name
        self.familyName = family
        self.phoneNumbers = phone
        self.emailAddresses = email
    }

    class func generateModelArray() -> [ContactModel]{
         let contactStore = CNContactStore()
         var contactsData = [ContactModel]()
         let key = [CNContactGivenNameKey,CNContactFamilyNameKey,CNContactImageDataKey,CNContactThumbnailImageDataKey,CNContactPhoneNumbersKey,CNContactEmailAddressesKey,CNLabelPhoneNumberMobile] as [CNKeyDescriptor]
         let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: key)
         try? contactStore.enumerateContacts(with: request, usingBlock: { (contact, stoppingPointer) in
             let givenName = contact.givenName
             let familyName = contact.familyName
//             let emailAddress = contact.emailAddresses.first?.value ?? ""
            let email : [String] = contact.emailAddresses.map { ($0.value as String) }
//             let phoneNumber = contact.phoneNumbers.first?.value.stringValue ?? ""
            let phone : [String] = contact.phoneNumbers.map { $0.value.stringValue }
             let identifier = contact.identifier
            var image : UIImage?
             if contact.thumbnailImageData != nil{
                 image = UIImage(data: contact.thumbnailImageData!)!
             }
             contactsData.append(ContactModel(identi: identifier, img: image, name: givenName, family: familyName, phone: phone, email: email))

         })
         return contactsData
     }
}
```

First Table View did Select Row :

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      if let storyboard = self.storyboard
      {
         let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "InsertContactViewController") as! InsertContactViewController
         vc.strTitle = "edit contact"
         vc.contactModel = dataArray[indexPath.row]
         vc.delegate = self
         self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
      }
   }
```

Add button In first VC :

```
   @IBAction func btnAdd_DidTouch(_ sender: Any) {
      let story = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
      let vc = story.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "InsertContactViewController") as! InsertContactViewController
      vc.isCreateContact = true
      vc.delegate = self
      self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
   }
```

VC 2 :

```
var contactModel : ContactModel!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
}

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 0 {
            return 1
        }else if section == 1{
            return contactModel.phoneNumbers.count
        }else if section == 2 {
            return contactModel.emailAddresses.count
        }
        return 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            let cell0 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "InsertTableCell0") as! InsertTableCell0
                 //////crash happend here
            cell0.txtFirstName.text = self.contactModel.givenName
               //////crash happend here
            cell0.txtLastName.text = self.contactModel.familyName
            return cell0
        }else if indexPath.section == 1 {
            let cell1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "InsertTableCell1") as! InsertTableCell1
            cell1.btnDelete.addTarget(self, action: #selector(deleteRowDate(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            cell1.txtPhoneNumber.placeholder = "Phone Number"
            cell1.txtPhoneNumber.text = contactModel.phoneNumbers[indexPath.row]
            return cell1
        }else {
            let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "InsertTableCell2") as! InsertTableCell2
            cell2.btnEmail.addTarget(self, action: #selector(deleteRowDate(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            cell2.txtEmail.placeholder = "Email"
            cell2.txtEmail.text = contactModel.emailAddresses[indexPath.row]
            return cell2
        }
    }
```

Comment: change `var contactModel : ContactModel!` to `var contactModel : ContactModel?`. app will not crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass a new reference of ContactModel in InsertContactViewController.

code:

```
@IBAction func btnAdd_DidTouch(_ sender: Any) {
  let story = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
  let vc = story.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "InsertContactViewController") as! InsertContactViewController
  vc.isCreateContact = true
  vc.contactModel = ContactModel() // pass a new reference 
  vc.delegate = self
  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Model:

```
class ContactModel : NSObject {
    var identifier : String?
    var thumbnailImageData : UIImage?
    var givenName : String?
    var familyName : String?
    var phoneNumbers : [String]?
    var emailAddresses : [String]?

   // rest of your code
}
```

NOTE: change var `contactModel : ContactModel!` to `var contactModel : ContactModel?`. app will not crash.

Comment: when i Changed  this contactModel : ContactModel! to this var contactModel : ContactModel? , Xcode Show 39 Error with this Value  : Value of optional type 'ContactModel?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'familyName' of wrapped base type 'ContactModel'

Comment: pass the empty object mode like this ContactModel(). but before it remove all `!` it from models otherwise app get crash.

Comment: Sorry, but without modifications in `ContactModel` your code will crash, too.

Comment: tnx for your answear bro . but there is a problem in second VC i try to handle it but icant . the problem it is when i try your way xcode show alot of error with this value : Value of optional type '[String]?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'count' of wrapped base type '[String]' . for example : contactModel.phoneNumbers.count ,  this line shoud convert to this : contactModel?.phoneNumbers.count or somthing else ?

Comment: Yes, it will take max 5 minutes to fixed all the errors. it is a good approach to solved your issue. Now it is upto you.

Comment: tnx you so much

Answer (score 0):

First of all **never ever** declare properties as implicit unwrapped optional which are initialized with an `init` method. Declare them as non-optional – if the parameters are non-optional – or as regular optional (?)

And delete the default initializer `init()` which makes the other initializer required (and reliable)

```
class ContactModel : NSObject {
    var identifier : String
    var thumbnailImageData : UIImage?
    var givenName : String
    var familyName : String
    var phoneNumbers : [String]
    var emailAddresses : [String]

    init(identi: String,img: UIImage?,name: String,family: String,phone:[String],email:[String]) {
        self.identifier = identi
        self.thumbnailImageData = img
        self.givenName = name
        self.familyName = family
        self.phoneNumbers = phone
        self.emailAddresses = email
    }
```

```
override init()
{
    super.init();
}
```

In VC 2 declare `contactModel` as optional

```
var contactModel : ContactModel?
```

and in `numberOfRowsInSection` use optional binding to safely unwrap the optional, the `switch` statement is clearer.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    guard let model = contactModel else { return 0 }
    switch section {
        case 0: return 1
        case 1: return model.phoneNumbers.count
        case 2: return model.emailAddresses.count
        default: return 0
    }
}
```

Force unwrap the other occurrences of `contactModel` in `cellForRow` which is only called if `contactModel` is not `nil`.

Finally add a line to reload the table view in `viewWillAppear`

Comment: tnx for your answear . in your way xcode show alot of error with this value : Value of optional type 'ContactModel?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'familyName' of wrapped base type 'ContactModel' .  for example : contactModel.phoneNumbers.count , this line shoud convert to this : contactModel?.phoneNumbers.count or somthing else ?

Comment: Please read my answer to the end. I wrote *Force unwrap the other occurrences of `contactModel` in `cellForRow` which is only called if `contactModel` is not nil*